# SQL ORDER BY specified order before between condition

Tags: sql, t-sql

This is a part of my pagination query that select 8 records:

```
 SELECT * FROM #Results  
        WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1 
 ORDER BY ad_type ASC,NEWID()
```

But that first select 8 records and then order by them.

I want to first order by all of the records and the select 8 next records without any duplication of records in next page fetch .

This is my first page result:
[image]

And this is the second page result:
[image]

In the second page there is a record with ad_type 2 that it should be in the first page instead of last record in the first page result

And this is all of my procedure:

```
GO
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAdPageWise]  
        @PageIndex INT = 1  
       ,@PageSize INT = 3  
       ,@PageCount INT OUTPUT  

       ,@state_id int=NULL
    AS  
    BEGIN  
          SET NOCOUNT ON;  

SELECT  Id,ROW_NUMBER() OVER  
            (  
                  ORDER BY Id   
            )AS RowNumber 
      ,ad_title
      ,ad_brief  
      ,ad_pic
      ,ad_type    
INTO #Results
FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.ID ORDER BY a.ID) AS rn, a.Id
      ,a.ad_title
      ,a.ad_brief  
      ,a.ad_pic
      ,a.ad_type    
    FROM [tbl_ads] a LEFT JOIN tbl_inf_adstate b ON a.Id=b.ad_id 
    WHERE (b.state_id=@state_id OR @state_id IS NULL) 
    AND a.ad_is_accept=1 
    AND a.ad_is_show=1 
    AND a.ad_is_slide=0 
)x
WHERE rn = 1


          DECLARE @RecordCount INT  
        SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*) FROM #Results  

          SET @PageCount = CEILING(CAST(@RecordCount AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) / CAST(@PageSize AS DECIMAL(10, 2)))  
        PRINT       @PageCount  

        SELECT * FROM #Results  
        WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1  ORDER BY ad_type ASC,NEWID()

        DROP TABLE #Results  
    END
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You're too late. The row number has to be already ordered, otherwise it's quite useless :) You need to add the ordering you want to the `row_number() over (order by ...)` clause that you're using to create `#Results`. Assuming you actually need `#Results` in the first place :)

Comment: I would need sample data, desired results, and entire query to help you.

Comment: Your `ORDER BY` criteria aren't deterministic - even without the filtering, you can't guarantee that two runs of the query would sort rows identically. You first need to choose some *deterministic* sorting criteria before sorting the rest of this out - get rid of `newid()`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever How can I choose some deterministic sorting ?

Comment: You have to identify enough columns in your data such that every row will always have unique values across those columns (unlike currently where mutliple rows have the same `ad_type` value). You then need to include *all* of those columns in your ordering/paging logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to show all the ads of a specific ad_type together, so you should be ordering by that first. I am assuming this based on the results shown, there is no "duplication" but rather the first set is `ad_id` between (1,45) and the second batch is (46,58).

To do that, just change the following line (the `PARTITION BY` is not needed as we just want to create one long list of row numbers from 1 to n):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.ID ORDER BY a.ID) AS rn, a.Id
```

to:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.ad_type, a.ID) AS rn, a.Id
```

But I do see some other issue with the query to point out:

1. With the solution presented above it assumes the data will not be changing beneath you. Assuming rows are only added (and `ad_id` is always increasing) that wasn't much of a problem before, but now that we are sorting by `ad_type` first and then `ad_id`, this can be more of an issue and should be accounted for if necessary.
2. To make sure there is not a bug in the logic of your join, you should place a unique constraint on `tbl_inf_adstate.ad_id`, or you will need to change the join, as it would duplicate rows from `tbl_ads` in your results.
3. If you are using SQL Server 2012 or greater, you may want to [take a look at the new paging functionality it offers.](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23811.paging-a-query-with-sql-server.aspx#Paginacao_dentro)

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT a.Id
          ,a.ad_title
          ,a.ad_brief  
          ,a.ad_pic
          ,a.ad_type    
     FROM [tbl_ads] a 
     LEFT JOIN tbl_inf_adstate b 
       ON a.Id = b.ad_id 
      AND a.ad_is_accept=1 
      AND a.ad_is_show=1 
      AND a.ad_is_slide=0
    WHERE b.state_id = @state_id 
       OR @state_id IS NULL             
    order by a.ad_type, a.Id 
   OFFSET (@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

[ORDER BY Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx)